# How to pass two parameters in android?

Tags: android

Hello I want to pass the two variables(ref and log) from my fragment to my avtivity but the log isn't displayed in my edittext. Can you help me to correct my code please?
It semms that the log is empty in the second activity because tid2 is empty
but I didn't understand the reason?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewProduitC.class);
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String tid = map.get("ref");
    intent.putExtra("ref", tid);
    String tid2 = map.get("log");
    intent.putExtra("log", tid2);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

activity
log is empty. why?

```
et_login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_login);;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        log = intent.getStringExtra("log");
        String ref2 = intent.getStringExtra("ref");
        et_login.setText(log);
```

Comment: are u sure that `tid2` contains a non-empty string before passing it to the activity?

Comment: you are right. it seems empty but why it's displayed correctly in my first fragment et_login = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.et_login);
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        log = intent.getStringExtra("login");
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        et_login.setText(log);

Comment: u mean inside `onItemClick()` method, `tid2` has a non-empty value ?

Comment: yes I updated my post to check why tid2 is empty?can you check this for me because I didn't understand the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check tid,tid2 are non-empty strings, If they contains value then in fragment try to print them in Log

Comment: only the tid2 is empty. I updated my post to check why tid2 is empty?can you check this for me because I didn't understand the reason

Comment: try to print in Log statement in  your Itemclick  like Log.e("String :",tid2); if it is empty then check the map that the values are adding or not

Comment: It reurns  FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: println needs a message means tid2 is empty string. I think your map contain no values first add the values and then check

Comment: How  can I add values in the map?

Comment: you can add it in your showEmployee(String json) method, I am not getting what you want to pass exactly. If you want to pass et_login text then simply pass et_login.getText.toString